# Is it possible to to have higher variances for predictions in Universal Kriging?

Tags: kriging, regression

I am using gstat to do Universal kriging.

I am finding that the variances for the  predictions of a hold out sample (i.e., new spatial locations for which I want to determine the response variable) are extremely large.

Infact, they are larger than my actual predictions. How is this possible?
Unless I am missing something , aren't the variances a representation of the confidence levels of the predictions ?